# How to normalise sequencing and qRT-PCR data for joint correlation analysis

Tags: correlation, normalization, bioinformatics

We would like to analyse the correlation between cytokine (IL-6) and miRNA expression.

However, we quantified the cytokine level in samples, in which the miRNA expression was quantified using either sequencing or qRT-PCR methods. Therefore, the miRNA expression in a part of the samples (n= ±40) is defined as the read count and the rest of the samples (n= ±30) is defined as ΔCt. The sample selection for both methods was random. The cytokine level in all samples was measured using the same method in one run.

We would like to perform the correlation analyses in all ~70 samples, but there are two different quantification units of the miRNA expression. We assume that the normalization of raw data independently in sequencing and qRT-PCR datasets and then follow-up joining both datasets could allow us to analyse the correlation using Kendall’s tau.

I would like to ask whether our approach applies to the correlation analyses using Kendall’s method or if there is a better approach.

Here is an example of our suggested approach:

```r
# data
set.seed(1234)
data_qrt <- data.table(mir = rnorm(20,2,5),
                       il = rnorm(20,40,15))
data_seq <- data.table(mir = rnbinom(20, 3, mu = 500),
                       il = rnorm(20,40,15))
  
# normalization
data_qrt_scaled <- data_qrt %>% 
  mutate(mir = scale(mir) %>% as.vector )

data_seq_scaled <- data_seq %>% 
  mutate(mir = scale(mir) %>% as.vector )

data_scaled <- data_qrt_scaled %>% 
  bind_rows(data_seq_scaled)

# correlation analyses
res_kendall <- psych::corr.test(data_scaled$mir, data_scaled$il, method="Kendall")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to assume implicitly that the samples analyzed by qPCR and those analyzed by sequencing have the same underlying distribution of miRNA levels. That could be a dangerous assumption.

The simplest work-around would be to do the rank-correlation tests separately on the two groups of samples. If the results agree then you have made your point: IL-6 and this miRNA tend to change in parallel.

Having 35 versus 70 cases in an analysis doesn't cut your ability to detect a true correlation by half, as you might fear. These things tend to go with the square root of the number of cases. That's not great, but it could be good enough.

You might combine the two data sets if you had a calibration curve that could translate reliably between read counts and qPCR results. Given batch effects in both sequencing and qPCR, however, that would be risky unless you did that calibration at the same time and under the same conditions that you did the original qPCR and sequencing.

Comment: Dear EdM, thank you very much for your comment and suggestion. We will consider the next step. osgarion